# Make extension to SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I'm trying to add a property to SKSpriteNode class, by making extension, but it fails on run.

Here I declare an extension:

```
extension SKSpriteNode {
var figureNumber:Int? {
    get {
       return self.figureNumber
    }
    set {
        self.figureNumber = newValue
    }
}}
```

And here I create my sprite:

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "1.png")

sprite.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
sprite.size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
sprite.zPosition = 2
sprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
sprite.name = "small"
sprite.figureNumber = 1
addChild(sprite)
```

It fails with error SKSpriteNode.figureNumber.setter.
Any ideas what's the problem?

Comment: Try using `self.figureNumber` in your extension's getter. `figureNumber` is being interpreted as the setter/getter, not the backing variable.

Comment: Same error. Xcode compiles it, but then app fails on run.

Comment: xCode prints Thread: 0 SKSpriteNode.figureNumber.setter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting a computed property from within its own setter, so you're dying of infinite recursion.

As it stands, there's no reason to have the setter/getter you've provided — if all you're doing is getting and setting, just having the declared property itself is fine:

```
var figureNumber: Int?
```

If what's actually going on here is that you wanted to have some additional logic in that setter/getter, what you actually need is to pick one of these two alternatives...

#### `didSet`/`willSet`

If you want to perform some side effect upon a property being written, add a property observer. For example:

```
var figureNumber: Int? {
    didSet {
        texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "\(figureNumber).png")
    }
}
```

#### A separate property

In Swift, the backing storage for a property (what you appear to be trying to access) is not accessible. If your logic requires controlling backing storage (for example, to make a property whose value is computed on demand, cached for later use, *and* can have its cache cleared when needed), use a computed property and a separate, private stored property:

```
private var figureNumberStorage: Int?
var figureNumber: Int! {
    get {
        if figureNumberStorage == nil {
            figureNumberStorage = generateFigureNumber()
        }
        return figureNumberStorage
    }
    set(newValue) {
        figureNumberStorage = newValue
    }
}
```

(This example does the clearable-cache thing, and wraps it as an IUO so you can set it to nil without having to worry about it being nil when you access it. Not that you really need the whole caching business for just an integer...)

---

At least, that's what you could do *if you were implementing a class/struct*. In an extension, you can't add stored properties, so you'll have to find another place to put backing storage for your computed property. In the case of `SKNode`, the `userData` property gives you a convenient place to store other stuff associated with a node:

```
let NumberKey = "number"
extension SKNode {
    var number: Int? {
        get {
            return userData?.valueForKey(NumberKey) as? Int
        }
        set(newValue) {
            if userData == nil {
                userData = NSMutableDictionary()
            }
            userData?.setValue(newValue, forKey: NumberKey)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not just declare var figureNumber: Int?, xCode says that Extensions may not contain stored properties.

Comment: Eh, forgot about that. :) Edited answer with workaround.

Comment: FYI, in the latest swift: `'valueForKey' has been renamed to 'value(forKey:)'`